# How would losing your soul translate to science?

Tags: medicine, death

So I hope my question doesn't cost me too much!

I'm making a game with a lot of lore associated with it. The thing to know is this:

> in a world were humans are captive from a higher power, two sciences were developed: science as we know it today and soul science: a science where a soul is assumed and build on that very fact.

Soul and regular science do translate from one to another, in this fictional science the brain is controlled by messages transmitted by the soul, except for one concept:

> when an individual loses his soul, he gets transported to limbo, leaving his body behind

In other words, his body simply stops functioning: brain activity ceases, cells don't duplicate, the heart stops beating. All of this is done in a way that regular people wouldn't notice (so no internal/external damage, heart attack, stroke, etc...). As far as we know it he lost consciousness and stopped functioning.

If there is a medically explained way to describe this what would it be? A death that seems invisible to most people?

Comment: The best idea I can think of is that the soul, whatever it is, happens to be intimately connected with the nervous system, and upon departure, leave massive injury to the nerves, hence causing damage and probably death. The stuff about how bodily functions stop is a bit problematic, since those processes are mostly automatic given the right chemical environment.

Comment: A simple answer to this would be: would people notice someone who get nervous damage?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the part where you said the loss of soul is supposed to be unnoticeable. In that case, the termination of cellular processes and the such would also be quite conspicuous--the body would turn cold and stiff, muscles will stop working without live cells, the flesh will rot without immune responses, the person would become vegetative from lack of brain activity etc. Some kind of magic seem necessary here.

Comment: His heart stops beating but it's unnoticeable? How does that make sense?

Comment: Somebody who has a heart attack usually knows that's something is wrong. Hell some people can immediately tell when someone has a heart attack

Comment: If cells stop duplicating, then *that's* a pretty obvious smoking gun. When a person dies, various cellular lines survive for appreciable amounts of time. Also, heartbeat is regulated by the brain but has an independent electric 'clock' - brain death does *not* equal heart stopping.

Answer (score 2):

Most "invisible" causes of death will stem from the nervous system - it's hard to observe externally.

From an evolutionary standpoint, humans may (?) be more likely to survive to reproduce if they stop spending energy on the brain once the soul has left. This will only happen in rare cases (soul isn't all the way gone, or the body keeps itself alive, etc), but it provides a reason for the soul to be necessary for consciousness -  as opposed to that being an autonomous function.

---

- **Kill all brain cells.** This is similar to @Tell's idea of removing myelin, which will stop brain cells from communicating. However, there may not be a specific command you can give cells that tells them to strip off that material. Suicide, however, is a command cells are [programmed to receive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoptosis) - and often do receive - so it may be more feasible to kill all brain cells instead of stripping them.
- **Cease signal transmission.** You may get away with avoiding physical changes altogether. If you tell cells to absorb all signals received, [brain death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_death) will occur. Everything will be perfectly intact before decay sets in, but the "spark" that travels the circuits will be missing, like a turned-off machine. This can happen physically if the brain is able to [produce certain molecules](http://www.oertner.com/PDF/EvankoHighlight.pdf) - no promises there - or if cells are programmed to receive a "lie dormant" signal.
- **Do nothing.** If the soul is needed to tell the brain what to do, there is no reason for it to say "shut down" on the way out. The brain will likely die. Alternatively, if that is painful, the soul can say "go to sleep".

Answer (score 1):

What about [myelin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myelin) ceasing to function? 
It is after all the substance that dictates our habits, and thus our choices, as well as the functionality of our organs. 
Normally, this will present as degrading ability to navigate space, and a decrease in general health. If all myelin stopped function, it would probably cause a breakdown of the body, as internal communication would cease.

Comment: Good thinking. The soul leaving could tell the brain to kill all myelin in one shot. Let's see if anyone else has another answer

Answer (score 1):

I think the first question you have to ask yourself is this: How are these brains different from real world brains? Given that our brains function just fine only using biochemistry, you'd have to take away some functionality and replace it with the operations of the soul, if you want to avoid the soul being simply redundant.

The most drastic way of doing this would be by not having a real brain at all, just a type of **"receiver lump"**; an organ with the sole function of connecting to the soul. As far as I understand, Descartes thought that the pineal gland was pretty much this. But if you want to follow Descartes and say that the pineal gland is the seat of the soul, you'd have to ask yourself, "what does the rest of the brain do?"

The Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy has a really good article on this: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pineal-gland/
Mind you, the article also points out a lot of flaws with this idea.

There is also another side to this: Presumably you want to do something in your world with the souls in limbo, so the function of the soul must be comprehensive enough for us to recognize whatever gets transported into limbo as a person. For example, in the article linked above, Descartes ascribes sensory perceptions, the forming of memories and "appetites and passions" *to the body*. As "pure actions of the soul" the article mentions "doubting, understanding, affirming, denying and willing" - without memory or emotional reaction, these don't make up something we would recognize as a person. So if you make the physical brain do too much, you end up with either redundancy or a mutilated soul.

In short, I don't see a way for the brain to be anything but a receiver in your scenario.
Maybe a more elegant way to go about this would be to miniaturize and spread out the function of the "receiver lump": In this version individual neurons are unable to process information. When the neurotransmitters trigger their receptors, nothing much happens in the physical neuron; but the neuron has a soul-neuron corresponding to it, and the electrical energy just vanishes into the soul-neuron, where the different inputs come together and the output is determined. The soul-neuron then triggers (or does not trigger) an impulse, by sending energy out into the physical world again (or not). In this version of the brain, neurons in the brain simply aren't built to deal with the impulses they get – without the soul the impulses dissipate without being able to trigger anything. Once the soul is gone, the brain doesn't do squat.

Conversely, once the body is gone, the soul-neurons lose the connections between them – but you could have them simply regrow these connections on their own, or postulate that one attribute of limbo is reestablishing these connections. It's your concept of the soul after all, you can assume whatever you want.

Comment: Brain as antennae. That is curious idea.